# Custom error page on HTTP 400 Error not working on Azure ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, azure

I'm trying to have a custom error page working on Azure for all HTTP Errors.

On my dev machine everything is working fine, on Windows Azure it works for HTTP404 but I still have a YSOD for HTTP400.

Here is what I have in my web.config

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="PassThrough">
        <clear />
        <error statusCode="400" path="~/Error" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        <error statusCode="401" path="~/Error" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        <error statusCode="403" path="~/Error" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        <error statusCode="404" path="~/Error" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        <error statusCode="500" path="~/Error" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>

<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error" />
    .....
</system.web>
```

Any idea of where to look to solve that?

Thanks in advance